# ASP .NET Core MVC, Entity Framework, Identity - composite key consisting of foreign keys

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have the following model classes. I want that TripId and TouristId would be a composite key of Attendance entity.

For now I get this error while the sql is executed:

```
CREATE TABLE [Attendance] (
[Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[TouristId] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
[TripId] int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Attendance] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Attendance_AspNetUsers_TouristId] FOREIGN KEY ([TouristId]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Attendance_Trip_TripId] FOREIGN KEY ([TripId]) REFERENCES [Trip] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Attendance_Trip_TripId' on
> table 'Attendance' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
> ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
> KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
> errors.

```
public class Attendance
    {
        public virtual Trip Trip { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Tourist { get; set; }
    }

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    { 
    
        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

public class Trip
    {
        public int TripId { get; set; }
        public string TripDate { get; set; }
        public int TripDuration { get; set; }
        public int TripLength { get; set; }
        public int TripSeats { get; set; }
        public Trail Trail { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser Guide { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
public class Attendance
    {
        public int AttendanceId { get; set; }
        public int? TripId { get; set; }
        public int? TouristId { get; set; }
        public virtual Trip Trip { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Tourist { get; set; }
    }
```

But foreign keys are still set as 'NOT NULL'.

Answer (score -1):

In `DbContext` class into the `OnModelCreating` overriding do this :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Attendance>()
.HasOne(p => p.Tourist)
.WithMany<ApplicationUser>()
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade `or` DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I get error (CS0308) in the 3rd line: The non-generic 
 ReferenceNavigationBuilder<Attendance, ApplicationUser>.WithMany(string?) method cannot be used with type arguments. 

And when it comes to the 4th line: my vs treats 'or' as a sytnax error.

Comment: I have change your method to this: 'modelBuilder.Entity<Attendance>()
.HasOne(p => p.Tourist)
.WithMany()
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);' 
But still the same error